# pycharm does not warn for unused variables and import

Tags: pycharm, settings

Suddenly my pycharm stopped warning for unused variables or unused import [coloring these lines in gray]. I searched everywhere in the setting and inspection and could not find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable it again by going `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` and in *Python* category, find `Unused local` and `Unresolved references` and next to them place checkmark to enable them.

Comment: I already set what you suggested but the problem was that my file was not in the project and therefore the inspection did not work on it. When i added it to the project it works

Comment: I have the same problem and I know it worked before on my installation.
The settings are already activated and the file I want to check is in my project. But still Pycharm says there are no warnings for my file, even though there are several unused variables.